# Use of \ExplSyntaxOn and \ExplSyntaxOff

Tags: packages

Have got a style file using underscore with function and variable names.
I use `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` as expected.

But I am encountering some difficulties in my knowledge.

Suppose I include some key definitions and then define some new commands.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { mystyle_teorema_keys }
  {
   name .tl_set:N = \mystyle_teorema_name_tl,
   label .tl_set:N = \mystyle_teorema_label_tl,
   shared .tl_set:N = \mystyle_teorema_shared_tl,
   parent .tl_set:N = \mystyle_teorema_parent_tl,
   pigment .tl_set:N = \mystyle_teorema_pigment_tl,
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Then in my document I call `\usepackage{mystyle}` followed by the command from my style file.

```
\usepackage{mystyle}
\mystyleCommand
```

Would calling `\mystyleCommand` have a problem accessing the underscore variables in my style file because the use of underscore has not been enabled in `document.ltx` ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148794/discussion-on-question-by-veak-use-of-explsyntaxon-and-explsyntaxoff); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

As covered in [my ansewr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697089/allowing-underscores-in-expl3/697093) to a related question, TeX fixes the catcode (interpretation) of tokens when they are first read. Thus if you have a file containing say

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\foo{\some_code_function:}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

then when you use `\foo` in a 'normal' document context, TeX will still see `\some_code_function:` in the replacement text.

This idea of 'hiding' control sequences from the document namespace goes back to Knuth, who uses `@` as a 'letter' in internal code in plain TeX, but who sets `@` as an 'other' char when typesetting.