# Allowing underscores in expl3

Tags: latex3

It has been argued to me that it is dangerous to change the hyphen `-` as a normal character in style files because one might break a lot of code, negative numbers, overbar accents, table markup, ... all likely to break.

Doesn't the underscore with `\ExplSyntaxOff` also lead to similar problems ?

I am starting to think that originally disallowing underscores `_` in names was in actuality a design mistake.

Comment: No, underscore has none of those problems as it is not part of the syntax of TeX the way  `-` is.  `-` is part of the syntax of a number. `_` has been used in l3 code since about 1990 we really do have a lot of experience here

Comment: allowing underscores in names would make a lot of math a lot harder to enter (and certainly couldn't be done now without breaking a large part of the existing corpus of  tex documents) `\alpha_1, \alpha_2,...`  requires `_`  not to be a letter or it is the undefined command `\alpha_` not a subscript.

Comment: Right.  Then the use of `\ExplSyntaxOff` (i.e. disallowing `_`) is primarily meant for making the entering of math commands in documents easier.

Comment: math was the start of tex, Knuth's decision to use `^` and `_` goes back to the mid 70's it's theoretically changeable but not if you want end users to recognise the syntax as tex.

Comment: That's quite fair enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX sets the category code of a character when it is tokenized. That means that if we have code using a 'letter' from outside a-zA-Z, we only need to worry about what's happening *where the catcode is set*. Thus for example in `expl3`:

```latex
\cs_new:Npn \foo #1 { \__mypkg_internal_foo:n {#1} }
```

defines `\foo`, which will use `\__mypkg_internal_foo:n` *even if we have changed the catcode of `_`*.

The only issue in normal TeX usage with `_` begin a 'letter' is that it's used for subscripts. So if we want to produce a subscript within `expl3` code we need to 'generate' the correct character token: `` \char_generate:nn { `\_ } { 8 } ``

We could do the same with other chars: the obvious one is `@`, used by plain TeX and LaTeX2e. Using `-` is more 'interesting' as in an expression such as `\count10=-5\relax`, TeX requires `-` is 'other'. That is a real issue, and is one reason in `expl3` we've not yet found a way to 'set' the catcode of all potentially-active chars.

Comment: This has been an answer at an excellent level.

Answer (score 2):

Not really. The main two purposes of underscores in the LaTeX syntax are:

1. Math subscripts, e.g. `\alpha_i`
2. File address and URLs such as `my_file.tex`

As `expl3` is mainly intended for actual programming, math content is rare, and in the few cases where you need to write something like *α<sub>i</sub>*, you can type`\alpha\sb{i}` instead of `\alpha_i`. So the first use of underscores doesn’t really cause issues within `expl3`. And as far as I know, the second use of underscores is not affected by the changing of catcodes within `expl3`, so this doesn’t really cause issues either.

Comment: Good elaboration.  I making good sense of things now.  Then `_` does not cause many problems (there are various workaround), unlike `-` which would be problematic.