# Undefined control sequence for equation in command

Tags: equations

I have a command to display the forward and inverse fourier transform but I get an undefined control sequence.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \begin {equation}F{f(t)}=F(\omega )=\int_ 
                                          {-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)\cdot e^{-i\o
l.151
```

Although it might look that `expl3` need not be used, I have the code in an `expl3` library.  Thusly I cannot avoid using `expl3`.

Here is a document using it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wvfourier { O{fwd} }
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {fwd}
          {
            \begin{equation}
              F{f(t)} = F(\omega) =
               \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)
               \cdot e^{-i\omega t} \, dt
            \end{equation}
          }

        {inv}
          {
            \begin{equation}
              F^{-1}{F(\omega)} = f(t) =
               \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)
               \cdot e^{i\omega t} \, d\omega
            \end{equation}
          }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\wvfourier

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\sb` instead of `_` when using math subscripts in `expl3` mode.
This was already addressed here:
[Allowing underscores in expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697089/allowing-underscores-in-expl3)

I also removed the `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` because this is probably not good practice.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \wvfourier { O{fwd} }
  {
    \str_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {fwd}
          {
            F{f(t)} = F(\omega) =
              \int\sb{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)
              \cdot e^{-i\omega t} \, dt
          }

        {inv}
          {
            F^{-1}{F(\omega)} = f(t) =
              \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\sb{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega)
              \cdot e^{i\omega t} \, d\omega
          }
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[\wvfourier\]

\[\wvfourier[fwd]\]

\[\wvfourier[inv]\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's zero reason to use `expl3` here at all.